# Python says string is not in list even though it is

Tags: python, string, list

I'm attempting to recreate Wordle as an exercise and need to get a guess from the user and then compare it to a list of valid words.

Even when I input a string that is in the list, it's treated as if it isn't.

```
        guessLoop = True
        while guessLoop == True:
            guess = str(input("Enter your guess\n"))
            if guess in allValidGuesses:
                print(guess+' is a valid guess')
                guessLoop = False
            else:
                print(guess+' is not a valid guess')
```

I changed the code to this:

```
    guessLoop = True
    while guessLoop == True:
        allValidGuesses.append('test')
        guess = 'test'
        if guess in allValidGuesses:
            print(guess+' is a valid guess')
            guessLoop = False
        else:
            print(guess+' is not a valid guess')
```

To make sure the string was imported correctly, I made it print before it compares the guess. I also set the guess to a string that is in the list according to what it prints:

```
    guessLoop = True
    print(allValidGuesses)
    while guessLoop == True:
        guess = 'zoned'
        if guess in allValidGuesses:
            print(guess+' is a valid guess')
            guessLoop = False
        else:
            print(guess+' is not a valid guess')
            break
```

When it prints I can see that for "zoned" is in the list, but is still not considered a valid guess.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CjHS.png)

Comment: Your input is not in the list.  Please include the code that defines `allValidGuesses` for the purposes of this example; my guess is that you have a typo, or a list of ints that you're comparing against a string, or something like that.

Comment: Without seeing the value of `guess` or `allValidGuesses`, I am inclined to believe Python over your claim that `guess in allValidGuesses` should be true.

Comment: Unrelated to your question -- you don't need `guessLoop == True` (just say `while guessLoop`), and you don't need `str(input(...))` (just call `input()`, it always returns a string).

Comment: from the screenshot: you don't have a list of strings, you have a list of lists. So when you do `"hello" in [[..], ["hello"], [...]]` it will return False. What you have in the list is `["Hello"]` and not `"Hello"`  You must first convert allValidGuesses to a list of strings doing `allValidGuesses = [i[0] for i in allValidGuesses] `

Comment: @Samwise Good to know thank you. I've also updated the post with more information and definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot of the output, you can see that the `allValidGuesses` list is a list of lists ie, `[["foo"], ["bar"]]`, as opposed to `["foo", "bar"]`
Therefore, `"foo" in allValidGuesses` will return False, whilst `["foo"] in allValidGuesses` will return True

Comment: Thank you. Very obvious now that it's been pointed out. Oh well. Good to know

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend setting the code up in a way to make it easy to debug & test. This lets you inspect the code for issues very quickly.

Here is an example:

```py
def check_guesses(allValidGuesses, debug=False):
  guessLoop = True
  while guessLoop == True:
    guess = str(input("Enter your guess\n"))
    if guess in allValidGuesses:
      print(guess + ' is a valid guess')
      guessLoop = False
    else:
      print(guess + ' is not a valid guess')
      if debug:
        print("allValidGuesses: ", allValidGuesses)


def test1():
  check_guesses(allValidGuesses=["abc", "DEF"], debug=True)


test1()
```

When I run the code I get the following output & it seems to work correctly:

```
Enter your guess
a
a is not a valid guess
allValidGuesses:  ['abc', 'DEF']
Enter your guess
abc
abc is a valid guess

```

A few things to consider:

1. Is `allValidGuesses` different from what you expect?
2. Are there some issues with upper/lower casing?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just did something similar and updated my post before seeing this. I printed the list and set "guess" to one of the list items that were just printed, though it still says it is invalid. There is a screenshot showing this attached, they are both lowercase and the printing makes sure that allValidGuesses is working as expected.

Comment: @Sandstone6574 no, the print shows allValidGuesses is not a list of strings but a list of lists, so it's not working as expected. That's actually what the problem is.